# Maven 2 - dependency type directory

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

In order to get a file I can use the following dependency

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>some group</groupId>
    <artifactId>art</artifactId>    
    <version>1</version>
    <type>some type</type>
    <scope>system</scope>    
    <systemPath>path to file</systemPath>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What can I do in order to get a directory?

Comment: Are you trying to add an unjarred dir to the classpath? You cannot. Are you trying to add all the jars in a dir? YOu should load them into a repository instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven works with jar dependencies. It appears you want to create and use your own local repository.

Please refer [How do I Create a Jar And Install It In My Local Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_create_a_JAR_and_install_it_in_my_local_repository) from Maven Docs.

Hope it helps.